# Single-line input fields align

Tags: html, css

I have been searching the net, but I haven't found a solution to the problem.

Here is HTML code:
http://jsfiddle.net/tA7VT/

```
<p>Enter your name:<br><input type='text' name='name' size='30'></p>

<p>Your age:<br><input type='text' name='age' size='10'> years old</p>

<p>Provide your location info:<br>
<input type='text' name='street' style='padding-left: 10px' size='50' placeholder='Street and house number'><br>
<input type='text' name='city' style='padding-left: 10px' size='30' placeholder='City or town'>
<input type='text' name='zip' style='padding-left: 10px' size='11' placeholder='ZIP'></p>
```

Neither '11' nor '12' for last `size` attribute make two fields' width same with the very first `input`.

I've tried to put all the field to `div` with width set as 100%, but then 60% and 40% don't fit, as well. I would like to know how can I make that second line to have the same width with first one?

Comment: please post your code here, so others do not have to go to another site to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using width in your style as opposed to `size`

```
<p>Enter your name:<br><input type='text' name='name' size='30'></p>

<p>Your age:<br><input type='text' name='age' size='10'> years old</p>

<p>Provide your location info:<br>
<input type='text' name='street' style='padding-left: 10px; width: 315px;'placeholder='Street and house number'><br>
<input type='text' name='city' style='padding-left: 10px; width: 200px;' placeholder='City or town'>
<input type='text' name='zip' style='padding-left: 10px; width:100px;' placeholder='ZIP'></p>
```

Comment: Using `width` with absolute values causes changing some kind of `margin-left` of `input` element. It is very insignificant, but still undesirable.